# How to improve accuracy when working with PSTricks?

Tags: pstricks, conversion, calculations, units

I have tried this with TikZ that produces the same issue, you can try [Leo's solution here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22763/what-is-the-tikz-equivalent-for-the-following-pstricks-code/22764#22764). In other words, this issue is **NOT** specific to PSTricks.

The hidden idea is to avoid cropping with `pdfcrop` so I can improve my web-based system performance. Here I prepare a high resolution bounding box by setting the paper size in advance to tightly fit the PSTricks objects.

To get a simpler conversion constant, I also define a new unit for my own purpose, e.g., `xp` that stands for `xport` as follows:

```
1 inch = 2.54 cm = 2.5 xp = 72 bp
```

From this convention I have:

- `1 xp = 1.016 cm` It means there is an excessive of `0.16 mm` for `1 xp`
- `1 xp = 28.8 bp`

Here is the minimal working example for a standalone PSTricks picture.

```
% gridoff.tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter
\def\xpbp#1{\strip@pt\dimexpr 28.8 \dimexpr #1 pt\relax\relax bp}
\makeatother
\usepackage
[
paperwidth=\xpbp{4.01},
paperheight=\xpbp{3.01},
margin=0bp
]{geometry}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{unit=\xpbp{1},linewidth=\xpbp{0.01}}
\pagecolor{cyan}
\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](\paperwidth,\paperheight)
\psframe(\paperwidth,\paperheight)
\pscircle*[linecolor=red](2.005,1.505){1.505}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

Note: I set the page color to cyan to ease me to identify whether or not the excessive strip exists in my main document importing the image.

I compiled it with

```
latex %1
dvips -R -t unknown %1 -o
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None -dCompatibilityLevel#1.5 -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress %1.ps
pdftops -eps %1.pdf
```

I got the following PDF result:

[image]

and EPS:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
% Produced by xpdf/pdftops 3.02pl4
%%Creator: dvips(k) 5.99 Copyright 2010 Radical Eye Software
%%Title: gridoff.dvi
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%DocumentSuppliedResources: (atend)
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 116 87
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 115.49 86.69
```

Note: There are rounding error in `%%HiResBoundingBox` above. The exact values should be `115.488` and `86.688`.

I must confirm that this issue is not specific to my own unit `xp` but it also happens in cm. If you try the following code, you will get a cyan thin strip at the top.

```
% incm.tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4cm,paperheight=3cm,margin=0bp]{geometry}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{linewidth=0.01cm}
\pagecolor{cyan}
\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{pspicture}(\paperwidth,\paperheight)
\psframe(\paperwidth,\paperheight)
\pscircle*[linecolor=red](2,1.5){1.5}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Problems and Questions:

However, when I magnified the PDF image 6400 times, I noticed there is a blue thin strip at the bottom as follows:

[image]

It should not be there because in theory PSTricks use `dimen=outer` by default.

1. How to make the resulting EPS have exact high resolution bounding box `0 0 115.488 86.688` rather than `0 0 115.49 86.69`?
2. How to force PSTricks to work more accurately to get rid of the excessive strip as shown above?

Comment: At the beginning I assumed there is a conversion error because of not-so-simple constant 28.3464567 (=72/2.54) so I created my own unit as shown above. Apparently, my assumption is wrong. My simple constant 28.8 also produces the same issue. Now, I make a new prediction that that issue might be caused by internal PSTricks calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is nearly impossible to get a correct image for such small values like the line width and the different units for PDF/PS and TeX: This one for example is correct.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[paperwidth=120bp,paperheight=90bp,margin=0pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{unit=1bp}
\psset{linewidth=2}
\pagecolor{cyan}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\paperwidth,\paperheight)
\psframe(120,90)
\pscircle*[linecolor=red](60,45){45}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

And another one with other values and other rounding errors will not.

Comment: There is a new issue emerged. If we compile your code above, the resulting EPS does not have `%%HiResBoundingBox`. It has only `%%BoundingBox`.

Comment: Why should it have a hires bounding box? It is exactly `120 x 90`

Comment: Using `bp` makes us difficult to plot a polynomial graph. Do you have idea?

Comment: you have several conversions between different units. You cannot avoid rounding errors which are _not_ seen when you print the image or view it with a magnification less than 1000%. I have more than 1000 images in my PSTricks book, all inserted as a pdf image and you will not be able to see any problem with the always existing rounding errors.

Comment: It is the last question in this topic. Is it guaranteed that we get an exact result if all dimensions are set in integer multiples of `1 bp`?

Comment: No, not in general! `bp` is not the TeX unit, you _always_ have conversions between TeX and `pdf/ps`.