# What is the TikZ equivalent for the following PSTricks code?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have learnt TikZ several months ago and I almost forgot because I seldom use it.
I have a simple and easy object to draw as follows.

[image]

```
% incm.tex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4cm,paperheight=3cm,margin=0bp]{geometry}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\psset{linewidth=0.01cm}
\pagecolor{cyan}
\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{pspicture}(\paperwidth,\paperheight)
\psframe(\paperwidth,\paperheight)
\pscircle*[linecolor=red](2,1.5){1.5}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: the gray thick frame is not a part of object to draw, it is Adobe Acrobat background. :-)

Could you translate the above code in TikZ with exactly the same dimension?

I ask this because I am investigating [another issue here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22758/2099). I want to check whether or not the issue is specific to PSTricks.

---

For those who cannot parse the PSTricks code above, the following is the description.

1. I prepare a paper size of 4 cm wide and 3 cm tall.
2. A canvas occupies the paper size without spaces.
3. A black thin frame occupies the canvas, its rule equals to 0.01cm.
4. A red disk is at the center of canvas. The top and bottom rules of the black thin frame become the tangent lines of the red disk.

### Caution

In PSTricks, the outer part of a stroke is used to measure the dimension. It is not the case in TikZ because TikZ uses the middle.

---

Optional requirement, could you try the following compilation steps as well?

```
latex %1
dvips -R -t unknown %1
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None -dCompatibilityLevel#1.5 -dPDFSETTINGS#/prepress %1.ps
pdftops -eps %1.pdf
```

I have tried Leo's solution but I got two pages with one overfull `\hbox`. One is blank and one contains cropped version of object shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4cm,paperheight=3cm,margin=0bp]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagecolor{cyan}
\parindent=0pt
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.2cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\coordinate (delta) at (.5\pgflinewidth,.5\pgflinewidth);
\draw ($(current page.south west) + (delta)$)
  rectangle ($(current page.north east) - (delta)$);
\fill[red] (current page.center) circle (.5\paperheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I guess this result is what you want. I use a very thick line to show the border clearly. But the code needs caculation and is ugly for me.

Comment: I think it is `\filldraw` instead of `\fill`. Does `\pscircle*` draw and fill or only fill? I think it does both.

Comment: @Leo: Please see my last update above. Thanks.

Comment: @Leo: Have you considered that TikZ uses the middle part of its stroke?

Comment: @Martin: The starred version will use the stroke color as the fill color when filling the region.

Comment: @xport: I'm not sure which method should I use to avoid the picture to be put into the second page. There're many ways, but none satisfy me. (XeTeX will produce a one page pdf. It ignores the slight overfull.)

Comment: @Leo: it is not only the second page, the circle is cut on the bottom

Comment: @xport: Does it now stroke and fill or only fill? With TikZ it is `\draw` (for stroke), `\fill` and `\filldraw` (for both).

Comment: @Martin: Starred version will both draw and fill. The filling color is taken based on the line color.

Comment: @xport: See my update.

Comment: @Leo: You can also use `([shift=(delta)]current page.south west)` etc., instead of using the `calc` library.

Comment: @xport: In that case you should use `\filldraw` not `\fill`.

Comment: @Leo: There is a thin strip at the top. But it is enough to show that TikZ also produce the same issue. Accepted!

Comment: @Martin: But I cannot use `([shift=-(delta)]current page.north east)`. Thus I have to define a `(minus delta)` for north east point. BTW, this syntax is as long as `calc` library.

Comment: @Leo: Does `([shift=(-delta)] .. )` not work? I personally prefer to load only a minimum set of libraries and just wanted to point the syntax out to you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to get pdf's in the end, I would suggest the external library of tikz (compile with pdflatex --shell-escape, it will put the pictures in separate files name `file-figure0.pdf etc).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize % activat

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.01cm}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle (4cm,3cm);
\fill[red] (2,1.5) circle (1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

or use the preview package (it will put everything in one file):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\begin{document}

\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle (4cm,3cm);
\fill[red] (2,1.5) circle (1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}

\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=cyan] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,3cm);
\fill[red] (1,1.5) circle (0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Leo's answer has been accepted and it has shown that the cyan thin strip at the top cannot be avoided.